# Need to trim all the elements in the form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to trim all the trailing white spaces from the text elements of the form. I need to do it in minimal number of steps. As soon as i press onsubmit, it should trim all the white spaces and then perform the further operations. Is there any script available? If not then can you please help me to achieve my Goal. Currently i need to manual identify each element and then perform a trim like.

```
var username = myform.elements['username'].value;
username.trim();
```

How to generalize it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 $("form").children().each(function(){
this.value=$(this).val().trim();
})
```

will trim all textbox and textarea inside form tag but don't write unnecessary code inside form.

Comment: Sorry for making it of two line

Answer (score 21):

```
$('input').val(function(_, value) {
   return $.trim(value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var allInputs = $(":input");
```

to get all form elements. Iterated using each function and trim it.

It will be something like this (not tested)

```
var allInputs = $(":input"); 
allInputs.each(function() {
        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#yourformid').submit(function(){
 $(':input').each(function(){
   $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()))
})
  return true;
});
```

Comment: $(this).val($.trim($(this).val())) seems overkill to me. You already have a reference to the value using this.value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#formid').find('input:text').each(function(){
                $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
 });
```